# recordRTC gravar tela e microfone

Tags: javascript

estou trabalhando em um projeto aonde preciso gravar a tela e o microfone com RecordRTC.

Na bibliografia ele explica que para gravar a tela o código necessário é:

```
    stream = await navigator.mediaDevices.getDisplayMedia({
        audio: true,
        video: {
            mediaSource: "screen", // whole screen sharing
        }

    })
    recorder = new RecordRTC.RecordRTCPromisesHandler(stream, {
        mimeType: 'video/webm', 
        //    bitsPerSecond: 128000
    });

    recorder.startRecording();
```

na bibliografia também é esclarecido que para gravar o microfone o código necessário é:

```
    stream = await navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia({
    audio: true

    recorder = new RecordRTC.RecordRTCPromisesHandler(stream, {
        mimeType: 'video/webm', 
        //    bitsPerSecond: 128000
    });

    recorder.startRecording();
```

porem, não sei como juntar a gravação de tela com o microfone

link da biblioteca:
https://github.com/muaz-khan/RecordRTC/